# Authentication with JWT and JSONAPI

Tags: rest, authentication, jwt, json-api

I am implementing REST API using the following technologies/approaches:

- [JSONAPI](http://jsonapi.org/)
- [JWT token](http://jwt.io/)

I want to implement authentication endpoint, it should receive username and password in POST request in JSONAPI format and return JWT token in JSONAPI format.
But I see there are some contradictions that does not allow me to be 100% RESTful:

Let's name endpoint `/tokens`, because it actually creates tokens. Response would be also resource of type `tokens`, e.g:

```
{
  "data": {
    "type": "tokens",
    "attributes": {
      "value": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6IjEifQ.ivJ5P23wqVo3w31flg3aOu7er--Ijght_RrBf_MuqsU",
    }
  }
}
```

But how about request? `username` and `password` are properties of user, but they should be sent to `/tokens` endpoint. If I send `users` resource to `/tokens` endpoint it does not make much sense.

Is there a way around for this, to follow JSONAPI and keep API meaningful?

Comment: What I do in these cases is having a session object or entity which is the one containing the properties you mention and I wouldn't care they're from a user because the user is the one authenticating.

In any case, JSONAPI and REST are good guides to follow but apply your style when in need.

Answer (score 5):

> If I send users resource to /tokens endpoint it does not make much sense.

Why not? REST does not impose that you only send users to a user resource. Sure, when you CRUD operations on a user resource you'll do this via the user resource endpoint.

But to generate a token, it's totally reasonable to send a user resource to the token endpoint.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply.

> REST does not impose that you only send users to a user resource.

REST does not, but REST API specification does. That's the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You could also supply the user credentials via an HTTP Authorization header, or as part of the toplevel `meta` property of the JSON payload.